# Grails encoding downloadable file

Tags: http, grails

I'd like to encode downloadable file name. I want to set file name with polish letters like ą ę ć ż ź. This is my code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode("ŻżŹźĄą", 'UTF-8'))
```

It works on Chrome but MozillaFirefox shows it not correctly.

How to set encoding properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work. HTTP headers require implicitly either ASCII but upmost Latin 1 encoding. There is no standard to encode the name in UTF-8. Yolu will be better off if you decompose the letters. See this: [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Comment: Chrome and IE9 handles it so it's strange why Mozilla changes filename to sth like this %C5%BC

Comment: Actually, there *is* a standard to encode the parameter in UTF-8 (RFC 5987).

Comment: My second link points to that. It still does not matter because no browser supports this.

Comment: Michael-O: all major shipping browsers support RFC 5987.

Comment: Michael-O: well, IE9 does. Speaking of crappy: it took Apple until two weeks ago to fix Safari, and there's no update for Windows.

Comment: IE9 ist not available for Windows. Though I prefer Mozilla and/or Webkit-based products, you still have issues. It's best to avoid such an encoding for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Chrome and IE are buggy. "%" isn't special in Content-Disposition parameters, unless you use the encoding defined in RFC 5987.